# Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 Boots to Initramfs

Tags: boot, 16.04, encryption, initramfs

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP Pavilion Laptop 15-AW004NA.  It ran initially for a couple of weeks fine, but now only boots to initramfs.  I have re-installed Ubuntu a few times, it will typically work once or twice.  Then crash whilst doing a normal operation such as web browsing.  After which it wont boot past initramfs.

I have tried: -

manually running the fsck (with -y command it cycles through thousands of commands and CPU hikes up)
re-installing Ubuntu 16.04 (encrypted and non-encrypted discs)
installing Ubuntu 16.04 then upgrading to 17.10
installing Lubuntu 16.04

I have checked the hard drive using Smart Data and Self Tests, results looked fine.

Live boot works fine with Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

Any ideas how i can debug further???

Cheers 
Lizard

```
XXXX@Lizard-Laptop:~$ grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for sda3_crypt...
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop systemd-cryptsetup[746]: Volume sda3_crypt already active.
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop systemd[1]: Started Cryptography Setup for sda3_crypt.
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt.
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop systemd-fsck[751]: /dev/sda2: clean, 299/124928 files, 144327/499712 blocks
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop systemd-fsck[750]: /dev/sda1: 8 files, 870/130812 clusters
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.323111] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.323113] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.323123] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.323125] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.323140] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.429742]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [    4.430076] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [   35.639691] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
/var/log/syslog:Aug 31 19:12:21 Lizard-Laptop kernel: [   35.778035] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
XXXX@Lizard-Laptop:~$ 
XXXX@Lizard-Laptop:~$ ls -alt /var/crash
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root     4096 Feb 15  2017 ..
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Feb 15  2017 .
```

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Do you have a SSD? If so, what make/model?

Comment: Nope just Ubuntu on the hard drive and no its not solid state.  Model is WDC WD10JPVX-60JC3T0. Cheers

Comment: Let's run a manual fsck once more. See my brief answer, below. If it outputs more than the normal pass 1, pass 2, etc... then copy/paste that info into your original question, ping me at `@heynnema`, and I'll take a look for you. ps: also do `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and `ls -alt /var/crash` and copy/paste that into your question also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The second option seems to have worked.  Its been rebooted a few times and seems stable.                                                                   
 I have also pasted the requested logs above.

Comment: @Lizard88 the logs look fine. Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: No its just Linux.  Swiped Windows the day i got the laptop :-) Ive installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu will see how that goes.

Comment: (would love explicit instructions on booting to grub menu)

Comment: If you don't see the GRUB menu at boot time, you can hold down the SHIFT key at boot time to show it.