# Ubuntu 16.04 initramfs error when reboot

Tags: boot, 16.04, initramfs

I was rebooting the PC without doing any modification or installing any package, but the boot end with initramfs screen, I have tried all the method like running `fsck` from the initramfs terminal, but doesn't work. Then I created a LiveUSB and boot, then run `fsck` on the drive `/dev/sda6`.

However when I reboot the  intiramfs terminal appears again. This problem is happening frequently with my OS, all the time I have to reinstall the OS. Why this happens and how it fix permanently? My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: boot error]

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Please see if this helps: [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

On link from above post says:[Initramfs Prompt When Ubuntu Boots](https://proposedsolution.com/solutions/ubuntu-booting-to-initramfs-prompt/) : This can occur when you have installed Ubuntu on an NTFS Windows partition and Windows was incorrectly shutdown.
Solution:

(initramfs)exit

You may get something like this —

/dev/sda1: Unexpected …
fsck exited ….
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires manual fsck

BusyBox v1.22 ……

(initramfs)

… means etc etc.

Now use the following command

```
(initramfs)fsck /dev/sda1
```

(pl note that /dev/ is constant. sda1 is to be known from the line above — The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires manual fsck)

Here change sda1 with your

**2)** Another post [Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 Boots to Initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951023/ubuntu-16-04-17-10-boots-to-initramfs)

suggest this solution:

> To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...
>
> ```
> boot to the GRUB menu
> choose Advanced Options
> choose Recovery mode
> choose Root access
> at the # prompt, type sudo fsck -f /
> repeat the fsck command if there were errors
> type reboot
> ```
>
> If for some reason you can't do the above...
>
> ```
> boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
> start gparted and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
> quit gparted
> open a terminal window
> type sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX # replacing X with the number you found earlier
> repeat the fsck command if there were errors
> type reboot
> ```

---